# Can you clarify this referencing issue in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference, concept

I'm used to pointers and references, but I need some clarification on this point:

I have this method in my Node class:

```
def createNewNode(graph):
    #Create New Node Dictionary
    newNode = {}
    # Fill in Details for that Node
    newNode['NAME'] = 'Max'
    newNode['AGE'] = 22
    newNode['ID'] = 'DC1234SH987'
    #Add the Node to the Graph
    graph.addNode(newNode)
```

The scope of the `newNode` created is within the function `createNewNode()`. Now this Node is added to a list of nodes in the Graph class.

The Graph class has this function:

```
def addNode(self, node):
    self.nodeList.append(node)
```

Now the Graph class function `addNode()` just appends the node to the list of nodes in the graph class. After the call to `graph.addNode()` in the node class, when does the scope of the `newNode` variable stop existing?

Won’t the data that was appended to the list in the Graph class be invalid now?
Does `append()` makes a new copy of the object passed? Can you explain this to me?

(In this example, the graph just contains a list of nodes and the node is actually a dictionary with details.)

Comment: [9.1 and 9.2 of the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)  is a good read, As well as [3.1](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) and [4.1](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) of the Language Reference in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `newNode` goes out of scope, but the object it refers to is not destroyed.  You added another reference to that object by appending it to `nodeList`.  `append` doesn't make a copy, but it does create a separate reference to the same object.  A *name* goes out of scope when the function it is in ends, but an *object* is only garbage collected when *all* references to it are gone.

Comment: @VishrutReddi - this could be *visualized* by printing the [```id```](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#id), of the new node, inside the two methods and after the ```addNode``` method has *finished*.